# Xcode 11 URL Scheme

Tags: xcode, macos, deep-linking, url-scheme

I just found out that Xcode 11 supports deep linking but I'm not able to find any documentation on how to use it in order to open a project or a specific file in a project and move the cursor to a specific line of code.

If I try to open `xcode://` in a web browser, it asks me to open the Xcode itself, so it works but I don't know how to use it in order to reference a file.

Thanks in advance.

[image: info plist content]

Comment: I don’t think that’s possible.

Comment: So I don't see the utility to expose the URL Scheme :/